# Regex Error: The Expression took longer than 250ms to execute

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting an error while executing below Regex

```
/^"?(\w*\d*\s*-*\/*'*)+"?$/
```

It might be duplicated but I'm not able to find the exact solution.

Here is the scenario.The string can accept:

a: It can accept double quotes `" "` only in start and end of the string not in between.

b: Here are the thing that will only allow : Alphanumeric, forward slash("/"), hyphen(-), apostrophe(') and space.

When I enter this text : Hawaii-Newsletter-Wipppp.pdf its throwing me the error, you can check here: https://regexr.com/

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks In advance

Comment: If there is a `"` at the start and not at the end, is it OK? The problem here is the optional patterns inside a quantified group in the middle of the pattern, and it causes catastrophic backtracking with non-matching inputs. Try `/^"?[\w\s\/'-]+"?$/`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/F9zmeJ/1).

Comment: No, double quotes is optional. the requirement is if " is in the start then  it must be at the end of the string also.

Comment: If it helps, it does work in JS. It's still slow but it returns `false` (correctly) for the input of `Hawaii-Newsletter-Wipppp.pdf`. If the word does match, it returns `true` faster. On the other hand, the regex is not very well written and can be improved.

Comment: Ok, try `/^(?:"[\w\s\/'-]+"|[\w\s\/'-]+)$/`. Or `/^("?)[\w\s\/'-]+\1$/`

Comment: It's work, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the optional patterns inside a quantified group in the middle of the pattern, and it causes [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with non-matching inputs.

However, this is not the only problem with the regex, as it also allows unpaired double quotation marks.

To fix the regex use

```
/^("?)[\w\s\/'-]+\1$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KBaaUt/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `("?)` - Group 1: an optional `"`
- `[\w\s\/'-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_`, whitespaces, `/`, `'` or `-` (if `_` is not required, replace `\w` with `A-Za-z0-9`)
- `\1` - a backreference to Group 1 matching the same value as is captured into Group 1
- `$` - end of string.